# jQuery to make all child links of a given div open in a new window

Tags: jquery

I have a div with ID "MyDiv" in which I need all child anchors of this div to open in a new window.

I'm trying:

```
jQuery('#MyDiv.children() a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: you can get rid off the `.children()` in the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>[click here for jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uh9GY/)</sub>

```
$('#MyDiv a').attr ('target', '_blank');
```

If you are unsure about how this attributes works read up on it below:

- **[HTML a target Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)**

---

If you don't fancy the use of `target="_blank"` (it's often frowned upon when writing xHTML) you could bind a *click* event to the anchors and open a new window using javascript/jquery.

Such as in the below example:

<sub>[click here for jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TdpBq/1/)</sub>

```
$('#MyDiv a').click(function(ev) {
  window.open(this.href);
  ev.preventDefault   (); // see post comment by @nbrooks
});
```

Comment: +1 good answer. as an fyi, event.preventDefault() is a safer way to stop the click from following the `a`'s href, since it will still allow the click event to propagate to the parent. When you `return false` in this click, the click event won't be raised on any of the parent elements -- which might unintentionally disable something else.

Comment: @nbrooks true that, I'll update the snippet with the correct method - thank you.

Comment: no problem. Be sure to pass in the event though: `function(event) { /*...*/ }`, it's not automatically in the handler's scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the main selector. `.children()` is not a valid part of a css selector. If you add a <kbd>space</kbd> in the css selector, the following part of the selector will be searched in all child nodes. If you want to search in the direct child nodes only, you can use [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Child_selectors) instead. E.g. replace `#MyDiv.children() a` with `#MyDiv>a`:

```
jQuery('#MyDiv>a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

or you can use:

```
jQuery('#MyDiv>a').click(function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get rid off the `.children()` in the selector.

Markup:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <a href="http://wwww.google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://wwww.google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://wwww.google.com">3</a>
    <a href="http://wwww.google.com">4</a>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#MyDiv a').click(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); 
}); ​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLx2x/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for you

```
$('#MyDiv a').live('click', function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```